# Getting a logical error in the while condtion.How can i correct it?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Game {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    int Level, Str, Dex, Con, Int, Wis, Cha, HP, Bonus, bonusCounter;

    System.out.print("Enter Level : ");
    Level = sc.nextInt();
    if (Level <= 0) {
        System.err.println("Invalid Input!!");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    System.out.println("Enter Str :");
    Str = sc.nextInt();
    if (Str <= 0) {
        System.err.println("Invalid Input!!");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    System.out.println("Enter Dex :");
    Dex = sc.nextInt();
    if (Dex <= 0) {
        System.err.println("Invalid Input!!");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    System.out.println("Enter Con :");
    Con = sc.nextInt();
    if (Con <= 0) {
        System.err.println("Invalid Input!!");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    System.out.println("Enter Int :");
    Int = sc.nextInt();
    if (Int <= 0) {
        System.err.println("Invalid Input!!");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    System.out.println("Enter Wis :");
    Wis = sc.nextInt();
    if (Wis <= 0) {
        System.err.println("Invalid Input!!");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    System.out.println("Enter Cha :");
    Cha = sc.nextInt();
    if (Cha <= 0) {
        System.err.println("Invalid Input!!");
        System.exit(0);
    }

    System.out.println("\nLevel : " + Level);

    if (Str == 10) {
        Bonus = 0;
        System.out.println("Str : " + Str + "[" + Bonus + "]");
    }
    else if (Str < 10) {
        Bonus = 0;
        bonusCounter = Str;
        while (bonusCounter <= 10) {
            if (bonusCounter % 2 == 1) {
                Bonus=+1;
            }
            bonusCounter=+1;
        }
        System.out.println("Str : " + Str + "[-" + Bonus + "]");
    }
    else {
        Bonus = 0;
        bonusCounter = 10;
        while (bonusCounter <= Str) {
            if (bonusCounter % 2 == 0) {
                Bonus=+1;
            }
            bonusCounter=+1;
        }
        System.out.println("Str : " + Str + "[+" + Bonus + "]");
    }
```

The code should calculate a bonus value for the 6 variables. Each Bonus should be 0 at 10, cumulative +1 for each even number above 10 and -1 for each odd number below 10. This is just the first part of my code. The same method applies for the 6 variables. There is logical error in the while condition so the code doesn't produce the output. What can i do to fix it?

Comment: You can and should *debug* your code.

Comment: a) Please use the canonical form of lower case variables. b) Write a method, so that you can write `int level = getInt ("Level");` => 6 calls = 6 lines + 4 Lines for the method. Much better to understand and search for bugs.

Comment: Thank you luk2302..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
bonusCounter = +1;
```

with

```
bonusCounter += 1;
```